# Am i allowed to share a photo of Apple Maps

Tags: terms-of-service, legal-terms

I am developing a iphone application, and I want to know if I am allowed to share a map screenshot (photo) of a area that has my custom draings on it. I am using Apple Maps, and I want the user to be able to share this photo via sms,facebook...etc. Am I allowed to do this or is in violation of some terms of agreement of apple maps?

I looked over "[Apple Maps Terms of Use](http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/maps/terms-en.html)", and I'm not sure what to make of the following:

> You must not:
>   (b) access or use the Service in any manner that attempts to **copy**, extract, scrape or reutilize any portions of the data or content provided by the Service, including bulk downloads or feeds of map data or imagery, or the creation of any databases based upon results from the Service;
>   (c) **reproduce, modify**, translate, or create **derivative works** of the Service or any portion thereof;

Isn't my screenshot a modified or derivate copy/reproduction of their map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is misleading: You are not thinking about sharing "a photo", you are thinking about sharing *many photos*. That is very unlikely to be legal.

However, there is a URL scheme for Apple Maps, which is intended by Apple for sharing locations on Apple Maps. (Google for Apple Maps URL scheme) which can be used by applications.